Extensive merging of nested list with capacity restriction
I have a nested list on which I want to perform merging under certain restrictions.
This is my nested list:
   [[[0.0, 2.0], [6.0, 20.0]],
     [[0.0, 5.0], [6.0, 12.0]],
     [[2.0, 5.0], [20.0, 12.0]],
     [[3.0, 4.0], [12.0, 6.0]],
     [[0.0, 1.0], [6.0, 6.0]],
     [[2.0, 3.0], [20.0, 12.0]],
     [[0.0, 3.0], [6.0, 12.0]]]

Extensive merging of pairs with capacity restriction.
I want to merge pairs from a (one) nested list but there are several restrictions.

Capacity. The number of boxes (for simplicity I call it this way) per address is given in the second list.
Example: [0.0, 2.0], [6.0, 20.0] where [0.0, 2.0] represent address index 0 and 2 and the number of boxes that need to be collected is 6 and 20 respectively.

Merging can only be done if ...
a) ... the capacity is not exceeded. In this case I set it to 40. So for the first addresses, 0 and 2 the total capacity needed is 26.
b) ... The list of addresses (route) has the address/index on which it needs to merge on the left or right side.


For example: the next element is: [[0.0, 5.0], [6.0, 12.0]]. I already took [0.0, 2.0].
From [0.0, 5.0] I can see that 0.0 is already taken. 5.0 is not. I can put 5.0 before 0.0 because 0.0 is on the at the beginning (or end).
So, the new merged list becomes:
[[5.0, 0.0, 2.0],[12.0, 6.0, 20.0]]
Now, the capacity is at 38, so it is fine.
I will go through the whole example:
The next element is: [[2.0, 5.0], [20.0, 12.0]] but 2.0 and 5.0 are already in the same merged list, so I can skip this one.
The next element is: [[3.0, 4.0], [12.0, 6.0]] of which 3.0 and 4.0 are both completely new. Accept this as a new pair. (No merging yet).
The next element is: [[0.0, 1.0], [6.0, 6.0]], of which 0.0 is already in a merged list. 1.0 is not yet taken but 0.0 is in the middle of a merged list. 1.0 can not be added.
Put 1.0 aside in a " not_merged list "
The next element is: [[2.0, 3.0], [20.0, 12.0]], of which  2.0 is in one merged list and 3.0 is in another one. We could merge both lists because 2.0 and 3.0 are both at the end or beginning, but this would mean exceeding the capacity of 40.
We skip this one.
The next element is: [[0.0, 3.0], [6.0, 12.0]], of which 0.0 is in one merged list and 3.0 is in another one but 0.0 is in the middle of a merged list. Skip this one.
Eventually, we are left with these lists: [[5.0, 0.0, 2.0],[12.0, 6.0, 20.0]] and [[3.0, 4.0], [12.0, 6.0]]. Also, 1.0 could not be merged and is put in the not_merged list.
The code needs to iterate through the nested list, starting by accepting the first element standard.
EDIT:
I simplified my question to make a beginning with coding.
I removed the capacity part and first tried to merge the pairs.
My pairs are now:
pairs3 = [[0, 2], [0, 5], [2, 5], [3, 4], [0, 1], [2, 3], [0, 3], [2, 6], [1, 2]]

done_ind = []
done_merged = []
done_ind.extend(pairs3[0])
done_merged.append(pairs3[0])
all_points = []
for i in pairs3:
    all_points.extend(i)
all_points = set(all_points)
for i in range(1,len(pairs3)):
    print(done_merged)
    total = 0
    total_n = []
    for t in pairs3[i]:
        if t in done_ind:
            total+=1
            total_n.append(t)
    if total == 0:
        done_ind.extend(pairs3[i])
        done_merged.append(pairs3[i])
        print(done_ind)
    elif total == 1:
        total_n = total_n[0]
        for y in range(len(done_merged)):
            if total_n in done_merged[y]:
                indexx = done_merged[y].index(total_n)
                insert_point = list(set(pairs3[i])-set([total_n]))
                insert_point = insert_point[0]
                if indexx == 0:
                    done_merged[y].insert(indexx,insert_point)
                    done_ind.append(insert_point) 
                elif indexx == len(done_merged[y])-1:
                    done_merged[y].insert(indexx+1,insert_point)
                    done_ind.append(insert_point) 
        print(done_ind)
    elif total == 2:
        print("try to merge two lists if values to be merged are on the outside")
print("points not merged:", all_points - set(done_ind))


and what have you tried? you haven't posted any code attempt.

You will need to show input and output sample data as well as the code that's giving you problems

Though it's not directly related to your goal, why maintain separate linked address index and boxes lists rather than dictionaries? I mean, [[0.0, 2.0], [6.0, 20.0]] could be replaced with {0.0: 6.0, 2.0: 20.0} .

I simplified the problem by removing the capacity constraint and added the code I wrote.


What's the problem with your code?  2. It seems to me you'd better use doubly-linked lists / chains (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/doubly-linked-list-in-python/) for your purpose. 3. By the way, it's not very clear in your question that you want to chain the pairs and not merely merge them (I had to re-read the part about end/beginning to understand this): you should make it clearer.

